# Extract text from protected PDF on google drive

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I am trying to download a PDF contents and I already found some clues (I am using selenium in VBA). Here's the code

```
Sub TEST()
    Const sURL As String = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Jjs65PaIFxIudE7PcnEufbHKsEpEdjup/view"
    Dim bot As New WebDriver, sCode As String, r As Long
    With bot
        '.AddArgument "--headless"
            .Start "Chrome", sURL
            .Get sURL
            .Wait 5000
            
            Dim posts As Object
            Set posts = .FindElementsByCss(".ndfHFb-c4YZDc-cYSp0e-DARUcf p")
            Dim i As Long
            For i = 1 To posts.Count
            r = r + 1
                Cells(r, 1).Value = posts.Item(i).Text
                
            Next i
    End With
End Sub

Function StringReverse(ByVal txt As String) As String
    StringReverse = VBA.StrReverse(txt)
End Function
```

I could extract some strings but they are not understandable. The texts should be Arabic. I have throught it is just a kind of letters reversed but I couldn't get a correct result. The correct result is what appears on the url.
Is there a way to download the protected PDF ..?or any workaround to get the contents of the PDF?

Comment: Do you want a solution in Python or it has to be VBA?

Comment: If not possible in VBA then in python and I will try to study the steps and apply it in VBA.

Comment: I am getting output like "جمهورية مصر العربية" with Python which is what you are looking for right? Trying to get vba working but getting error number 33. Are you using this selenium driver from 2016? https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases

Comment: @Jortega I think you are right, that was the last release Florent published.

Comment: @Jortega this is the only text which is right and correct.  "جمهورية مصر العربية"

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do this in python. Adding some links in case you do not have python set up.

**Download Python:** https://www.python.org/downloads/

**(optional) Pycharm - Community edition is free:** https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=windows

**Chrome Driver:** https://chromedriver.chromium.org/

**Tutorial video with setup instructions:** https://youtu.be/FFDDN1C1MEQ

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Path\\to\\your\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Jjs65PaIFxIudE7PcnEufbHKsEpEdjup/view')


# text_elements_array = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//p")))
text_elements_array = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ndfHFb-c4YZDc-cYSp0e-DARUcf p")))
for p in text_elements_array:
    print(p.text)
```

Output text:
جمهورية مصر العربية

األكبدًََُّت انًهَُُّت نهًعهًٍُ يشكض حًُُّض يسهٍّ واقهًٍُ ودونٍ، َضًٍ
خىدة يُظىيت انخًُُت انًهَُُّت انًُغخذايت ألعضبء هُئت انخعهُى ، بششاكت
فبعهت يع كهُبث انخشبُت وانًذاسط وانًئعَّغبث األخشي راث انصهت.
٠ووف "أٚهكٞ ر١ل"اٌم١بكح "ثأٔٙب إٌشبؽ اٌنٞ ٠ّبهٍٗ اٌشقض ٌٍزأص١و فٟ إٌبً ٚعوٍُٙ ٠زوبْٚٔٛ
ٌزؾم١ك ثوغ األ٘لاف اٌزٟ ٠وغجْٛ فٟ رؾم١مٙب."
ث١ّٕب هوف "ثبً" اٌم١بكح "ثأٔٙب اٌوٍّ١خ اٌزٟ رزُ هٓ ؿو٠مٙب ئصبهح ال٘زّبَ ا٢فو٠ٚ ،ٓئؿالق ؿبلبرُٙ،
ٚرٛع١ٙٙب فٟ االرغبٖ اٌّوغٛة".)ؽَٓ ِؾّل ئثوا٘١ ُهّبْ، 6991 ،ص 43)
ٚ٠ووف وً ِٓ "ر١وٞ ث١ظ" - "عْٛ ثٛي رِٛبً" اٌم١بكح هٍٝ أٔٙب "هٍّ١خ ئٔغبى هًّ ِب هٓ ؿو٠ك
اٌزأول ِٓ أْ أفواك اٌغّوخ ٠وٍّْٛ ِوب ثـو٠مخ ؿ١جخ، ٚأْ وً فوك ُِٕٙ ٠إكٞ كٚهٖ ثىفبءح هبٌ١خ".
ٚ٠وٜ "ٍزٛول٠" "ًأْ اٌم١بكح ٟ٘ هٍّ١خ اٌزأص١و فٟ ٔشبؽ ِغّٛهخ ِٕلّخ ارغبٖ رؾم١ك ٘لف ِو١."ٓ
ث١ّٕب هوف "ع١ٛن" » «"أْ اٌم١بكح "ٟ٘ ِغّٛهخ ٍٍٛو١بد أٚ رظوفبد ِو١ٕخ رزٛافو فٟ شقض ِب،
ٚ٠مظل ِٓ ٚهاء٘ب ؽش األفواك هٍٝ اٌزوبْٚ ِٓ أعً رؾم١ك األ٘لاف اٌّو١ٕخ ٌٍوًّ، ِٚٓ ٕ٘ب رظجؼ
ٚك١فخ اٌم١بكح ٍٚ١ٍخ ٌزؾم١ك األ٘لاف اٌزٕل١ّ١خ".
6 -أِب اٌم١بكح اٌزوثٛ٠خ : ف١ّىٓ روو٠فٙب "ثأٔٙب "اٌوٍّ١خ اٌزٟ ٠زّىٓ ِٓ فالٌٙب اٌمبئل اٌزوثٛٞ أْ ٠إصو فٟ
رفى١و ا٢فو٠ٚ ٓ٠ٛعٗ ٍٍٛوُٙ".
ٚ٠ووفٙب "ِؾّل ِٕ١و ِوٍٟ" هٍٝ أٔٙب "اٌملهح هٍٝ رٛع١ٍٍٛ ٗن األفواك فٟ ِٛلف ِو١ ،ٓئم رمَٛ فٟ
عٛ٘و٘ب هٍٝ اٌزفبهً اٌنٞ ٠زُ ث١ ٓاٌمبئل ٚأفواك اٌغّبهخ".
ٚ٠ّىٓ روو٠فٙب أ٠ؼب هٍٝ أٔٗ "ل١بكح اٌمٜٛ اٌوبٍِخ فٟ اٌوٍّ١خ اٌزوثٛ٠خ، ٚرؾَ١ ٓاٌزفبهً االعزّبهٟ ث١ ٓ
أفواك٘ب ثـو٠مخ ِإصوح رؾمك روبُٚٔٙ، ٚهفن َِزٜٛ أكاءُ٘ ئٌٝ ألظٝ ؽل ِّىٓ، ِن اٌّؾبفلخ هٍٝ ثٕبء
اٌغّبهخ ٚرّبٍىٙب.
وًَكٍ أٌ َغخخهص يٍ يدًم انخعشَفبث انعُبصش انخبنُت نهقُبدة:
1 -أٔٙب هٍّ١خ رفبهً اعزّبهٟ، ئم ال ٠ّىٓ ٌإلَٔبْ أْ ٠ىْٛ لبئلا، ثّفوكٖ، ٚئّٔب ٠َزـ١ن أْ ٠ّبهً
اٌم١بكح ِٓ فالي ِشبهوزٗ اٌفوبٌخ فٟ عّبهخ ِب ػّٓ ئؿبه ِٛلف ِو١.ٓ
2 -أْ اٌم١بكح روزّل هٍٝ رىواه اٌزفبهً االعزّبهٟ.
4 -٠زُ ف١ٙب ارقبم لواهاد.
3 -رزـٍت طفبد شقظ١خ ِو١ٕخ فٟ اٌمبئل.
5 -رٙلف ئٌٝ رؾم١ك أ٘لاف ِو١ٕخ.
أّبؽ اٌم١بكح اٌزوثٛ٠خ اٌفوبٌخ

Output pic:
[image]

@YasserKhalil can you confirm the text in the 3 boxes in the picture below is correct.

[image]

---

---

---

Since you do not have Python set up here are some manual steps:

Open the browser and before going anywhere open Developer Tools (Ctrl + Shift + i)

Navigate to the view only pdf document in google docs with Developer Tools open in the browser.

Zoom out the page to 50% and scroll down to the bottom of the pdf so that all pages
are present.
Select the Console tab in Developer Tools.
Paste the following code below (and hit enter).

let jspdf = document.createElement( "script" );

jspdf.onload = function () {

let pdf = new jsPDF();

let elements = document.getElementsByTagName( "img" );

for ( let i in elements) {

let img = elements[i];

console.log( "add img " , img);

if (!/^blob:/.test(img.src)) {

console.log( "invalid src" );

continue ;

}

let can = document.createElement( 'canvas' );

let con = can.getContext( "2d" );

can.width = img.width;

can.height = img.height;

con.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

let imgData = can.toDataURL( "image/jpeg" , 1.0);

pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG' , 0, 0);

pdf.addPage();

}

pdf.save( "download.pdf" );

};

jspdf.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.debug.js' ;

document.body.appendChild(jspdf);

Comment: I will not be able to apply that just now. Can you give me snapshot of the output?

Comment: Thanks a lot. But this what I got out of my code. The problem is in the output which is supposed to be in Arabic in a correct way while this is scrambled characters ..

Comment: @YasserKhalil Ok, I think I see what is happening here Arabic is read from right to left and not left to right correct?

Comment: To see the correct output for Arabic, have a look at the PDF contents itself which displayed on the page. In your snapshot, this is correct sentence. But not the other sentences.

Comment: @YasserKhalil are you scrapping it because you are not able to download it?  What if I had a download solution?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I failed to download so I tried to scrape the text contents.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216581/discussion-between-jortega-and-yasserkhalil).